# Why does the error “ syntax error at or near "DELETE"” occur?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following code. It works perfectly in online compiler, but when I run it on the notebook, I get the following error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "DELETE"

Here is the code:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT Block_id, MIN(step) step
    FROM tablename
    WHERE name = 'John'
    GROUP BY Block_id
)
DELETE FROM tablename t
USING cte c
WHERE c.Block_id = t.Block_id AND c.step <= t.step
```

Comment: I assume the table `tablename` exists?

Comment: What do you mean with "run it in the notebook"? Does it work without the CTE? `delete from tablename t using (select block_id ....) c where ...`

Comment: What postgresql version do you run? CTEs in `DELETE` were only added at 9.1 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-delete.html https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-delete.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no,this doesnt work either..

Comment: @Sid yes,of course